# odb база данных

Tags: windows, база-данных

Есть база данных в формате odb можно ли ее открыть в акцессе? и вообще как она работает в windows? Стабильно или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь про базу OpenOffice, то самой простой способ ее открыть - запустить OpenOffice (при необходимости - установить). Работает не хуже, чем MDB (БД MS Access).

Comment: А совместимость с акцессом поддерживается? просто надо прогу написать для винды. а у меня линуха стоит. Поставил лезврус и опен офис. вот и не знаю какую БД выбрать акцессную или еще какую.....

Comment: Рекоменую не парить мозг и просто подключить к проекту библиотеку работу с SQL. Во-первых, SQL - стандартный язык (и весьма мощный) для работы с БД. И он не зависит от того, в каком формате живет сама база. Хоть постгресс, оракл, опенофис или аццесс.  Во-вторых, есть множество библиотек, реализующих работу с БД. Вам ничего особо навороченного не надо, поэтому попробуйте Firebird: http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird